# Unable to read object content Spring Boot activemq

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to consume a POJO in the consumer side using Spring Boot and Active MQ. Message is received but not able to convert to actual type of the object with the below exception:

**Exception:**

```
2018-08-01 10:51:35.542  INFO 9280 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.JmsConsumer                  : Message reached in consumer side...
2018-08-01 10:51:35.542  INFO 9280 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.JmsConsumer                  : +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2018-08-01 10:51:35.547  WARN 9280 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getBody(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.example.JmsConsumer.receive(JmsConsumer.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
```

**POJO:**

```
public class OrderDetails implements Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double itemPrice;
    private double totalPrice;
    private String orderStatus;

}
```

**Publisher side:**

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.model.OrderDetails;
    @Component
    public class JmsProducer  {

        @Autowired
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

        @Value("${jsa.activemq.queue}")
        String queueName;

        public void send(OrderDetails msg) {
            this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, msg);
    }
```

**Consumer side:**

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    import com.example.model.OrderDetails;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

        @Component
        @Slf4j
        public class JmsConsumer {

  @JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.queue}", containerFactory="jsaFactory")
       public void receive(Message message) throws JMSException{
                log.info("Message reached in consumer side...");
                    log.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
          OrderDetails response = Message.getBody(OrderDetails.class);
       log.info("Application : object received : {}",response);
            }
      }
```

**Active MQ Config:**

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;

@Value("${jsa.activemq.broker.url}")
    String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${jsa.activemq.borker.username}")
    String userName;

    @Value("${jsa.activemq.borker.password}")
    String password;

    /*
     * Initial ConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.OBJECT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("id");
        return converter;
    }

    /*
     * Used for Receiving Message
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

        /*
     * Used for Sending Messages.
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

Active MQ config is same in both Publisher and Listener side. I have registered the message converter but I am not sure why the covertion from JSON to object is not working. Any pointers to solve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this error by consuming the POJO directly rather than consuming it as javax.jms.Message. Also the message converter Bean should be initialized as below:

// Serialize message content to json using TextMessage

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}
```

Please see my code in github:

https://github.com/sureshpec04/spring-boot-jms

Answer (score 0):

I think your jar has some issue .I think may be some older version jar you are using .Please check your jar version and JDK you are using

Comment: I am using JDK 10 and latest version of active mq(5.15.4). If jar is an issue how the publishing part is working?